# Weird in_array() behaviour

Tags: php, arrays

I have some trouble with the result of `in_array()`. It is not like I would have expected and as I understand the manual.

Simple test:

```
$_aOperatorsOneOptin = array('DE-010', 'DE-005');

$bMatchPaymentOperator = in_array(0 , $_aOperatorsOneOptin);

if($bMatchPaymentOperator)
    echo 'found';
```

I would expect that I would get no result with this, but $bMatchPaymentOperator is true!

I would expect that

```
$bMatchPaymentOperator = in_array('DE-010' , $_aOperatorsOneOptin);
```

is true , which it is.
But why oh why is the upper statement true?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I would not have thought that strict mode would be necessary here. I would have suspected it more in cases like 0== false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use third parameter of `in_array` to force strict match

```
<?php

$_aOperatorsOneOptin = array('DE-010', 'DE-005');

$bMatchPaymentOperator = in_array(0 , $_aOperatorsOneOptin, true);

if($bMatchPaymentOperator == true)
    echo 'found';
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you compare a number to a string in php, php converts the string to a number before doing the comparison. Strings that don't start with a number get converted to 0, so `0 == 'hello world';`

You can force in_array to check the data type as well as the content for an exact match by passing `true` as the third argument to `in_array()`.

```
$_aOperatorsOneOptin = array('DE-010', 'DE-005');

$bMatchPaymentOperator = in_array(0, $_aOperatorsOneOptin, true);

if($bMatchPaymentOperator)
    echo 'found';
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for details on comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Because of PHP's truthy/falsy weirdness, I'd expect.  Try:

```
$bMatchPaymentOperator = in_array('0' , $_aOperatorsOneOptin);
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to be in quotes:

```
$bMatchPaymentOperator = in_array('0' , $_aOperatorsOneOptin);
var_dump($bMatchPaymentOperator);
```

Result: `bool(false)`

Answer (score 1):

The weird behavior is happening because `0 == "this is a string"` i.e. `0 = any string` in php just check this simple example

```
<?php
if( 0 == "this is a string"){
    echo("true");
}
else{
    echo("false");
}
?>
```

**output : true**

hence the in_array function shows such weird behavior

so as to make your code work just add strict parameter of in_array to true

check this code

```
<?php
$_aOperatorsOneOptin = array('DE-010', 'DE-005');

$bMatchPaymentOperator = in_array(0,$_aOperatorsOneOptin,true);

if($bMatchPaymentOperator){
    echo 'found';
}
else{
    echo "Not found";
}
?>
```

**output: Not found**